# Conflicting OpenCV versions with cv_bridge

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

*Note: I'm on an Nvidia Jetson with Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS 1.*

After an installation of `cv_bridge` using `sudo apt install ros-noetic-cv-bridge` I keep on getting the following warning when building my project:

```
...

-- +++ processing catkin package: 'csi_camera'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(csi_camera)
-- Found OpenCV: /usr (found version "4.5.4") 
-- Installing devel-space wrapper /.../csi_cam.py to /.../csi_camera
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'vio'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(vio)
-- Found OpenCV: /usr (found version "4.5.4") found components: core highgui imgproc imgcodecs 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done

...

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.2, needed by /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5, needed by /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5.4, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2
```

Which doesn't seem to be a big issue, until I had to use `cv::circle` in my code. Now this line causes a `segmentation fault` (I checked that my image is valid, etc.).

```cpp
cv::circle(image, cv::Point(100, 100), 2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));
```

I tried removing both versions of OpenCV but `cv_bridge` needs some parts of 4.2 and CMake can only find OpenCV 4.5.4 (which is the version installed by `libopencv-dev`). I'm really not sure how to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue i.e.

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.2, needed by /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgcodecs.so.408

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.408, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.8.0, may conflict with libopencv_imgproc.so.4.2

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.408, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.8.0, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.4.2

so  I uninstalled :

> sudo apt remove libopencv-dev python3-opencv

> sudo apt purge libopencv-dev python3-opencv

which will also remove cv_bridge.
Then you have to build it from source using :

> git clone -b noetic https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv.git

and catkin_make. Normally the CMakelist.txt of the package is well formed and should find your opencv version in /usr/local/lib. You can [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345411/ros-question-how-to-compile-custom-cv-bridge-with-opencv4-correctly) if you have some more trouble.

Hope this helps !